# Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading

Tags: html, google-maps

> How to resolve "Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading "?!

when i insert the google map  in our html code then
I am getting the  error which is describe in attached image.

[image: when i insert the google map in our html code then I am getting the error which is describe in attached image.]

Comment: Strange that Google is using a directive that doesn't exist according to Mozilla MDN.  `ALLOWALL`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't control Google's HTTP headers, so you can't (short of getting a job where you do control them) make them [use valid options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options).