# Google Picker API Invalid origin value error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-picker

Today Google Picker stopped working in my Google Sheets add-on without any changes to the code. The error in the modal dialogue reads:

> Invalid origin value.

The errors in console are:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://docs.google.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://n-a6p4dqsl***d6wq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com')
>
> dropping postMessage.. was from unexpected window
>
> dropping postMessage.. was from unexpected window
>
> Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading 'https://docs.google.com/picker?protocol=gadgets&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2F&sdr=true&title&oauth_token=<oathToken>&developerKey=<developerKey>&hostId=n-a6p4dq***d6wq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com&relayUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fn-a6p4dq***d6wq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com%2Ffavicon.ico&nav=((%22documents%22%2Cnull%2C%7B%22selectFolder%22%3Atrue%2C%22parent%22%3A%22root%22%7D)%2C(%22documents%22%2Cnull%2C%7B%22dr%22%3Atrue%2C%22includeFolders%22%3Atrue%7D))&rpcService=qhurmoc5w4l7&rpctoken=xssf8g42xc2&thirdParty=true#rpctoken=xssf8g42xc2': 'ALLOW-FROM [https://docs.google.com/'](https://docs.google.com/%27) is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored.

It maybe that the error is linked to this line of code where I do `setOrigin()`:

```js
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .addView(driveView)
            .addView(drivesView)
            .hideTitleBar()
            .setOAuthToken(token)
            .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
        --> .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
            .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2,
                DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
            .build();
```

But this line is directly from the documentation of the Google Picker API and worked properly before. If I change `google.script.host.origin`, that returns `https://docs.google.com` as url to `https://n-a6p4dqsl***6wcd6wq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com`, I get the same error and a new one, so that is not it.

I also cannot add this as as an authorized javascript origin in the GCP project as it returns the following error:

> Invalid Origin: uses a forbidden domain

(This [has been the case of a while](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170740549))

This seems like a new error and I wasn't able to find an answer neither on Google's issues tracker nor on StackOverflow.

Anyone facing this as well or have an idea how it can be handled?

Comment: Same issue for us with an add-on as well. I believe that setOrigin line is converted into the X-Frame-Options directive using a header ALLOW-FROM that is now ignored, so causing the Invalid origin value error message as the response. I just found out in the X-Frame-Options documentation that ALLOW-FROM is an obsolete directive that no longer works in modern browsers. Don't use it ... Maybe they just started to drop it yesterday. I am guessing that might the actual reason

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Putting an end, the only way to solve this is to remove the trailing slash after

From

docs.google.com/

To

docs.google.com

Contrary,

The google.script.host.orgin gives the "https://docs.google.com/" which causes the error. Hence you need to hard code as

"https://docs.google.com"

Google has made some changes recently which might have bubbled this issue.

**UPDATE**

You can use this function - and call -  `...... setOrigin(getOrigin())`

```
function getOrigin() {
    var url = google.script.host.origin;
    return url.substr(url.length - 1) === "/" ? url.substr(0, url.length - 1) : url;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me..  To make it extra clear, this new hardcoded value goes in the `setOrigin()` call on the `PickerBuilder()` instead of the `google.script.host.origin` value that is there in the docs.

Comment: Thanks a million, this worked!
For those who don't want to hardcode the url, you can use the following function to strip the trailing slash:
`
      function stripSlash(url) {
        return url.substr(url.length - 1) === "/"
          ? url.substr(0, url.length - 1)
          : url;
      }
`

Answer (score 0):

Solution for use in a iframe

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#code.gs_2

code.gs

```
         function showPicker() {
          var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dialog.html')
              .setWidth(600)
              .setHeight(425)
              .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
          SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select a file');
    }


.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME); 
//can be removed or replaced with
.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
```

dialog.html

```
function getOrigin() {
        var url = "https://mydomain.name/";
        return url.substr(url.length - 1) === "/" ? url.substr(0, url.length - 1) : url;
    }
```

**Update**

Now it works without any changes in the code.