# Google Picker setVisible throw "Incorrect origin value. " error

Tags: javascript, google-picker

We have used the same code for about 2 years now, and now it no longer allows the picker to display. I reviewed [Google Picker API Invalid origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65632969/google-picker-api-invalid-origin-value-error) but seem unable to actually set the origin value. The picker initialization is below.

```
picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
.addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView().setIncludeFolders(true))
.setOAuthToken(token)
.setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
.setCallback(pickerCallback)
.setOrigin('https://docs.google.com')
.build();
```

The full error is

```
[Report Only] Refused to frame 'https://docs.google.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://docs.google.com".
3760914899-picker_modularized_opc.js:1112 Uncaught Error: Incorrect origin value. Please set it to - (window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host) of the top-most page
    at new KJ (3760914899-picker_modularized_opc.js:1112)
    at 3760914899-picker_modularized_opc.js:1115
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (picker:61)
rpc.js?c=1&container=onepick:127 Invalid rpc message origin.  vs https://host45.mydomain.com
```

The last line suggests the origin is an empty string or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reported issue on the Google's Issue Tracker like yours:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203793068

You can go there and star the issue to get updates on it.

As of now, there seems to be no explanation or resolution on it.