# Why is google drive picker affecting ext js combo field template?

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, google-api, google-picker

A couple years ago a former colleague added ext components, specifically the Combobox, to a project I maintain. Now I am trying to add [a google drive picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) to allow users to select items from google Drive. After a user loads the google picker, if he/she then interacts with the combobox, the results will not correctly be displayed, despite the XHR request returning the data properly. I see in the boundlist.js file where it creates the XTemplate object but not where it applies it to each record in the store...

[image: Combobox results display before and after utilizing the google drive picker]

Has anybody dealt with this issue or something similar? Is there a way to avoid conflicts between the two JS libraries?

Comment: What is a "google drive picker"?

Comment: Can you make a [sencha fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com) that exhibits your problem?

Comment: Any js errors in a console?

Comment: Serg - there don't appear to be any JS errors in the console related to the combobox... There are some related to the Google Drive Picker which appear (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658088/google-api-error-but-still-works) (which I know links to more SO questions :| )

Comment: @Aelliott1485 Js errors is what's causing this most likely, need to fix those first.

Comment: Well, as [Quentin said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145475/invalid-x-frame-options-header-encountered-when-loading#answer-16145732): "`You don't control Google's HTTP headers, so you can't (short of getting a job where you do control them) make them use valid options.`"

Comment: I tried making a Sencha fiddle but it won't let me add the google js file with its callback (`<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>`) I see in the browser console: `The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in 'https://fiddle.sencha.com/run?_dc=1461868927080' because its source code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header.` :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem with ExtJS 3.3.

It is because gdrive js client adds a function to the array prototype called values.
Subtemplate of combo's XTemplate has a target "callback" like this:

```
(function(values,parent
/**/) {
with(values){ return values; }
})
```

This "callback" is generated by Ext.XTemplate function. I modified that to generate "callback" like this:

```
(function(values,parent
/**/) {
if(typeof values.values != "function"){with(values){ return values; }} else {return values;}
})
```

Regards,
Gyula

Comment: Great - thanks! I found the place in the 4.0.5 source to modify - it is slightly different but not overly convoluted. Now I just have to get it into the compiled version :)