# Google reCAPTCHA v2: Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading

Tags: html, recaptcha

When I insert the google `reCAPTCHA` in our HTML  code, I am getting the error that is described in the attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include the image. However, do have a look at this. This might answer your question.

[Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145475/invalid-x-frame-options-header-encountered-when-loading)